# How to ignore iOS VoIP notification if call has already ended?

Tags: ios, voip, callkit, pushkit

We're developing a video calling application and rely on APNS VoIP notifications. Due to our design it sometimes happens that the VoIP notification arrives to the device when the call has already ended or the recipient has declined it (missed call for example).

The problem with that approach is that iOS requires you to report all incoming VoIP notifications in some way - either that there's new incoming call or the current call has been updated.

Is there any way to ignore the unnecessary/redundant VoIP notification? The current approach I came up with is really nasty i.e. first I report new unknown incoming call and then immediately I report its end. This causes the native call UI to be shown for a brief moment.

```swift
private var provider: CXProvider?
private var uuid = UUID()
//...
func ignorePushNotification() {
    self.provider?.reportNewIncomingCall(with: self.uuid, update: CXCallUpdate(),
                                         completion: { error in
                                            // ignore
                                         })
    self.provider?.reportCall(with: self.uuid, endedAt: nil, reason: reason)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there isn't a better way to ignore a VoIP Push. But I suggest you to improve the code as follows.

```swift
func ignorePushNotification() {
    provider?.reportNewIncomingCall(
        with: self.uuid, 
        update: CXCallUpdate(),
        completion: { error in
            self.provider?.reportCall(with: self.uuid, endedAt: nil, reason: .failed)
        })
}
```

Given the asynchronous nature of CallKit, if you don't do that, it could happen that the end of the call executes before the `reportNewIncomingCall`. It's probably very rare but it could happen.